# Transform cross-reference table into combination of rows and columns with their respective values

Tags: microsoft-excel, cross-reference, combine

I have a cross-reference table similar to this:

[image: Cross-reference table and expected result]

How do I combine both rows and columns to arrange them in 3 columns where their values are in the last column?

Is there any special Excel tool/function to achieve it?

Comment: This can be unpivoted in powerQuery, or a function using `MakeArray` with `ByCol` and `ByRow`. Maybe adding `vStack` to get the headers.

Comment: Thank you! Unpivot using Power Query was the right answer and it's the fastest way to do it. Youtube tutos have the "visual" way to do it.